# Concat specific string to every inserted row

Tags: sql

This is an hypothetical case..

I'm trying to find a good approach to make sure that every value inserted in an specific column `col1` of my table `mytable` has a specific string `http://` at the begining of the value.

Example:

I want to insert `myprofile` into `mytable` so (after my check condition..) the final value would be `http://myprofile`

I guess that a good approach could be using a trigger on insert but I didn't find anything concrete yet..

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget an update trigger too. (Or manage all inserts/updates using stored procedures, and have no insert/update privilege on the table directly.)

Comment: Yes, a trigger is definitely your way to go. Since those are **highly** vendor-specific, we'd really need to know the concrete RDBMS you're using - `oracle`, `sql-server`, `postgresql` etc.

Comment: Hi @marc_s , thank you for your comment (@jarlh too). It would be great to have an approach for SQL-SERVER and MYSQL, but if I have to choose one it would be SQL-SERVER.

Comment: Another way to force INSERT/UPDATE statements to start the string with `http://` (and I assume also `https://`?), is to use a `CONSTRAINT`. That way you are not responsible for handling this. If a statement would violate the constraint, the statement would fail. This best be well documented of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this as a starting point - this is for SQL Server (don't know MySQL well enough to provide that trigger code for you):

```
-- create the trigger, give it a meaningful name
CREATE TRIGGER PrependHttpPrefix
ON dbo.YourTableName            -- it's on a specific table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE            -- it's for a specific operation, or several
AS
BEGIN
    -- the newly inserted rows are stored in the "Inserted" pseudo table.
    -- It has the exact same structure as your table that this trigger is 
    -- attached to.
    -- SQL Server works in such a way that if the INSERT affected multiple
    -- rows, the trigger is called *once* and "Inserted" contains those
    -- multiple rows - you need to work with "Inserted" as a multi-row data set
    --
    -- You need to join the "Inserted" rows to your table (based on the 
    -- primary key for the table); for those rows newly inserted that 
    -- **do not** start with "http://" in "YourColumn", you need to set 
    -- that column value to the fixed text "http:/" plus whatever has been inserted
    UPDATE tbl
    SET YourColumn = 'http://' + i.YourColumn
    FROM dbo.YourTableName tbl
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON tbl.PKColumn = i.PKColumn
    WHERE LEFT(i.YourColumn, 7) <> 'http://'
END
```

Comment: Should follow jarlh's suggestion and put it `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`